# Error while downloading Unity IoC container from Nuget

Tags: c#, unity-container, nuget

I am building a console application for the sake of Inversion of control. I have tried to download "Unity" IoC container from nuget package manager, but got this error. Any help is useful. I am using visual studio 2010 pro.

[image: error while downloading package]

Comment: Try an [older version](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/3.0.1304.0).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like you are using .NET Framework 4 and  trying to add Unity 3. In the documentation of Unity 3 it says:

> System Requirements Supported architectures: x86 and x64.
>
> Operating systems: Microsoft Windows 8, Microsoft Windows 7, Windows Server 2008
> R2, Windows Server 2012.
>
> .**NET Framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5, .NET for Windows Store Apps (previously known as Windows Runtime)**

To use Unity in .NET 4 you need to use this package instead:

```
Install-Package Unity -Version 2.1.505.2
```

Answer (score 1):

From [unity.codeplex.com](https://unity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Unity3ReleaseNotes).

> System requirements Supported architectures: x86, x64, ARM. Operating
>   systems: Microsoft Windows® 8, Microsoft Windows® 7, Windows Server
>   2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Phone 8. Supported .NET
>   Frameworks: **Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5**, .NET for Windows Store Apps
>   (previously known as WinRT), .NET for Windows Phone. Rich development
>   environment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, Professional, Ultimate, or
>   Express editions.

So yes, use older version.